# is there a way to know the type of parent window (frame or dialog-based)?

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to know whether the parent window type is a frame window or a dialog-based window.

As we know the frame window can be created by `CreateWindow` function and dialog-based window can be created by `CreateDialog` function.
Also, I have tried to use `GetClassName` function but it gives me an unknown value "ex: #32770".

```
WCHAR clsName[50];
GetClassName(hWnd, clsName, 50);
MessageBox(hWnd, clsName, L"", MB_OK);
```

In case of a dialog-based window gives me #32770, but in case of a frame window gives me the project name, not the class name of the frame window.

**Is it possible to know the type of a parent window, and how**?

Comment: [*#32770 The class for a dialog box*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-window-classes#system-classes)

Comment: you might try comparing the window procedure of the window to that of the dialog class. Probably won't work when the window is subclassed or when the window is created through a dialog-template with a non-system windowclass.

Comment: *value is the project name, not the class name!* - why ? this is value of class name

Comment: Speculativ : a Dialog never has a parent (optionally an owner) and a FrameWindow must have a parent. No ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I think that way is not efficient, I want an efficient way which tells me whether the parent window is frame or dialog-based.

Comment: **I don't see any reason to vote me down, please tell me why?**

Comment: "Frame-based" and "dialog-based" are vague, or at least ambiguous.  Consider a traditional overlapped window that leverages the Dialog Manager or a completely custom window that emulates a dialog window.  If you tell us why you want to know, we might be able to guide you toward a specific attribute of the window you can check.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: I want to create a GUI library that provides you two types of the parent window (Dialog-based, Frame-based). Each type differs from the other in its code specifically in messages loop and the main procedure, so I want to know the type of parent window to specify appropriate messages loop and main procedure for that type.

Comment: If you're creating the parent window, you can expose that information to the child any way you like.  There's no magic bit in that can indicate the kind of window your custom framework created unless you provide that bit.

Comment: Child windows don't care, what their parent is. They just respond to messages. It's unclear what you would want to change in child windows knowing what their parents are. Unless you are going to replicate the [edit control fiasco](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070820-00/?p=25513).

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain [window style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-styles) attribute which was used by CreateWindow to create a window, over the [GetWindowLong](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowlonga), and then check the style.

I.e. something like:

```
::DWORD style = static_cast<DWORD>( ::GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE) );
if( WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW == (style & WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW) ) {
   std::cout<< "Frame" << std::endl;
} else if( WS_DLGFRAME == (style & WS_DLGFRAME) ) {
   std::cout<< "Dialog" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Is window style fixed and reliable to do that mission?

Comment: @Lion King from the documentation `After the window has been created, these styles cannot be modified, except as noted.`

Answer (score 1):

A [dialog box has class name #32770](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-window-classes#system-classes). So you can use that to distinguish between dialog boxes and windows that are not dialog boxes.